# How to parse byte string to byte object without eval

Tags: python

So i have a str that is actually a byte str. I want to parse it to a byte object without having to use eval as that is a potential code injection door.

```
# byte representation from empty string "" from pickle.dumps
data = "b'\\x80\\x04\\x95\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x8c\\x00\\x94.'"

eval(data) # This will work but i cant use it.
bytes(data) # This will fail
```

The `bytes` call fails with `TypeError: string argument without an encoding` but i have no way to know the encoding, eval does figure it out byitself tho.

Comment: "ast.literal_eval" should work.

Comment: Try `ast.literal_eval` https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: Also do note the warning and make some judgement: "This function had been documented as “safe” in the past without defining what that meant. That was misleading. This is specifically designed not to execute Python code, unlike the more general eval(). There is no namespace, no name lookups, or ability to call out. But it is not free from attack: A relatively small input can lead to memory exhaustion or to C stack exhaustion, crashing the process. There is also the possibility for excessive CPU consumption denial of service on some inputs. Calling it on untrusted data is thus not recommended."

Comment: the type of `pickle.dumps("")` is actually `bytes`. To convert a string to a byte class you can use `your_string.encode()`.